# Javascript redirect and wrong special chars encoding

Tags: redirect, character-encoding, special-characters, encodeuricomponent

I have this code to perform searches in my site:

```
var encoded = encodeURIComponent($("#searchBar").val());
location.href = sitePath + "/search/keyword/" + encoded;
```

Because i'm italian I use a lot chars like à è ù, but when I put them in search3w they're not correctly encoded.

If i try to console log encoded var it will print correctly encoded chars for URLs, but when the script does the effective redirect to te page i have things like http://www.mysite.it/search/à and chars are not well received.

Answer (score 0):

I think there can be a problem with encodeURIComponent function. Did you used firebug for debugging?

Regards,
dan8912

Comment: encodeURIComponent is a default javascript function, could it have problems? o.o

However, i noticed that in some sites special chars like à ò ù are used in search string and works perfectrly. Do you know how to do? 

Example: http://www.hdblog.it/index.php?s=%C3%A0